# Google Cloud Platform SDK network issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to upload a local folder to a bucket on GCP. 
I have Windows 7 Pro and no proxy server.

When running `gcloud init` I got a network diagnostic error.

```
Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...done.
ERROR: Reachability Check failed.
    Cannot reach https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform (error)
Network connection problems may be due to proxy or firewall settings.
```

I am still able to select a user and project thereafter.

So I turned my anti-virus, windows firewall and router firewall off, and run `gsutil ls` and `gsutil cp ...` as a test, and get the same error for both.

```
INFO 1002 22:35:04.327000 util.py] Retrying request, attempt #3...
INFO 1002 22:35:11.644000 util.py] Retrying request, attempt #4...
INFO 1002 22:35:26.417000 util.py] Retrying request, attempt #5...
INFO 1002 22:35:51.611000 util.py] Retrying request, attempt #6...
```

I am able to `ping www.googleapis.com`.

```
Pinging www.googleapis.com [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

And when I tested it on another computer it worked perfectly - so proves that its not a configuration issue on GCP Console.

I often use WinSCP in command prompt for SFTP transfers. Why will this one thing not work? Is this a OS or GCP SDK issue?

Comment: Can you check your gcloud version? Try 'gcloud components update', that sometimes fix weird issues. (Just fishing here.)

Comment: I tried that and did all windows updates too. I even tried re-installing.

Comment: Can you try to increase verbosity to debug? Do you get more info what goes wrong?

Comment: How did this get solved? Am having same issue. Reinstalled sdk and ran \